# How to add a user-defined body

Tags: box2d, shapes

I am a beginer of BOX2D, and I found I don't know how to CREATE a user-difined body from specific sprite. 
All box2d body shape are Polygon related shapes :(

Below I just wanna use a specific shape from specific sprite, thanks for your help in advance.

```
PhysicsSprite *rightSprite =  [PhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"mySpecificShape.png"];
[self addChild:rightSprite];

b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
bodyDef.position = b2Vec2(400/PTM_RATIO, 512/PTM_RATIO);

b2Body * bodyA = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
bodyA->SetUserData(rightSprite);
[rightSprite setPhysicsBody:bodyA];
```

Comment: You mean you want to create a shape that uses the outline of the picture contained in the sprite?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do it. You have to build your body from simple shapes: polygon, circle, edge.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this be an external tool , There are few tools that you can read about:

Vertex Helper , and Physics Editor.

I'm recommending on Physics Editor
in this tool you load you image , and its export the shape into a XML , than you can load it in the engine that you are using and it will collide in the proper why

You can read more and Download it here:

http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor/feature